# Can't run OpenCV example in fedora

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake, fedora

I'm trying to compile and run the DisplayImage OpenCV example from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#display-image but

`cmake` outputs:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/####/Desktop/OpenCV/image
```

`make` outputs:

```
Linking CXX executable DisplayImage
[100%] Built target DisplayImage
```

and `./DisplayImage image.jpg` outputs:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/hugo/Desktop/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 483
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/hugo/Desktop/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:483: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Both `libgtk2.0-dev` and `pkg-config` are already installed and on their lastest versions.

Comment: if you get that error, libgtk2.0-dev was not found when running cmake to *compile the  opencv libs* (not your program).  `cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << endl;` should tell.

Comment: That was quite useful. Thank you.